# Flutter: How to groupBy inside a MapEntry

Tags: flutter, dart

I have data like this:

```
[
  {
    "country": "United States",
    "continent": "North American",
    "located": "center"
  },
  {
    "country": "Mexico",
    "continent": "North American",
    "located": "southern"
  },
  {
    "country": "Guatemala",
    "continent": "North American",
    "located": "southern"
  },
  {
    "country": "Australia",
    "continent": "Australia",
    "located": null
  }
]
```

I used `groupBy` to group `continent` and got the result to display the `ListView` as shown below.

**However, I want to `groupBy` more with `located`**
*("United States" groupby "center", "Mexico" & "Guatemala" groupby "southern")*  to achieve the result like the image below.

[image]

So pls help me, this is my code so far:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListModel {
  String country;
  String located;
  String continent;

  ListModel({this.country, this.continent, this.located});
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = [
      ListModel(country: 'United States', continent: 'North American', located: 'center'),
      ListModel(country: 'Mexico', continent: 'North American', located: 'southern'),
      ListModel(country: 'Guatemala', continent: 'North American', located: 'southern'),
      ListModel(country: 'Australia', continent: 'Australia', located: null),
    ];
    List<MapEntry<String, List<ListModel>>> continentEntry = const [];
    continentEntry = groupBy<ListModel, String>(data, (e) => e.continent).entries.toList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: continentEntry.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final entry = continentEntry[index];
          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Text(entry.key),
              ),
              Column(
                children: entry.value.map((e) => Text(e.country)).toList(),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want `North America` and `Australia in center

Comment: @Jahidul Islam Nope, I want that `groupBy` with `located`, ex: United States grouped: "center",  Mexico and Guatemala group: "southern", it should display exactly the same as the image I've shown above

Comment: updated my answer if the located is empty will pass empty string(or like others) or you will group with continent

Comment: you want group by both continent and located ?

Comment: @Jahidul Islam Yup group by both `continent` and `located` :)

Comment: instead of `(e) => e.continent` you need to return both continent and located: the easiest (but not the best) solution is simply: `(e) => '${e.continent},${e.located}'`

Comment: @pskink is there any way to groupby `continent` first, then groupby  `located` inside `continent`? so that I could show `located` if it is != null

Comment: @Kel please have a look I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run and check and used [grouplist package](https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list)

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:grouped_list/grouped_list.dart';

class ListModel {
  String country;
  String located;
  String continent;

  ListModel({this.country, this.continent, this.located});
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ListModel> data = [
      ListModel(
          country: 'United States',
          continent: 'North American',
          located: 'center'),
      ListModel(
          country: 'Mexico', continent: 'North American', located: 'southern'),
      ListModel(
          country: 'Guatemala',
          continent: 'North American',
          located: 'southern'),
      ListModel(country: 'Australia', continent: 'Australia', located: null),
    ];
    List<MapEntry<String, List<ListModel>>> continentEntry = const [];
    continentEntry = groupBy<ListModel, String>(data, (e) => '${e.continent}')
        .entries
        .toList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: continentEntry.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final entry = continentEntry[index];
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Text(entry.key),
              ),
              GroupedListView<ListModel, String>(
                //physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                elements: entry.value,
                groupBy: (ListModel e) => '${e.located}',
                groupSeparatorBuilder: (String groupByValue) => groupByValue!="null"? Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:30),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    child: Text(groupByValue)):Container(),
                itemBuilder: (context, element) {
                  return Center(child: Text(element?.country ?? ""));
                },
                order: GroupedListOrder.DESC,
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ouput:
[image]

Comment: It works perfectly! this result's exactly what I wanted, thanks for your enthusiasm and your time xD

Comment: thank you for your great question and help me to learn something different