# How do I sort a list of element according to Delivery time of the orders in dart, Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bubble-sort

I am fetching a list of orders and storing the objects in a List. The object has a property called `String deliveryTime` and the times are in `'hh:mm a'` format. I want to sort the list by the deliveryTime of the objects in Ascending order. I created a list of String that has the deliveryTime only and used bubble sort to sort them in ASCENDING order. But I am having trouble sorting the entire list of objects in that order.

NOTE: The list of object has some `null` & `"ASAP"` as their `deliveryTime` value.

Here's the incomplete code:

```
List<OnlineDeliveryOrder> getSortedOrdersList(
    List<OnlineDeliveryOrder> orderList,
  ) {
    List<OnlineDeliveryOrder> tempOrderList = [];
    List<DateTime> sortedTimeList = [];
    print("List Length before Sort: " + orderList.length.toString());

    orderList.forEach((OnlineDeliveryOrder order) {
      if (order.deliveryTime != null && order.deliveryTime != "ASAP")
        sortedTimeList.add(DateFormat('hh:mm a').parse(order.deliveryTime));
    });

    sortedTimeList =
        sortedTimeList.toSet().toList(); //Taking the unique times only

    //Sorting times in asc order using bubble sort algorithm
    bool sorted = false;
    while (!sorted) {
      sorted = true;
      for (int i = 0; i < sortedTimeList.length - 1; i++) {
        DateTime tempTime;
        if (sortedTimeList[i].compareTo(sortedTimeList[i + 1]) == 1) {
          // dt1.compareTo(dt2) == 1 if dt1 is a later date than dt2
          tempTime = sortedTimeList[i];
          sortedTimeList[i] = sortedTimeList[i + 1];
          sortedTimeList[i + 1] = tempTime;
          sorted = false;
        }
      }
    }

    // HOW DO I SORT THE ENTIRE LIST
    
    print("List Length after Sort: " + tempOrderList.length.toString());
    // String time = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(element);

    return tempOrderList;
  }
```

**Can anyone please guide me on how can I return the sorted list?**

Comment: you can try the grouplist https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am using the grouped_list package to group the orders by Date. But I want to sort the items inside the group by their delivery time. For that I need to sort the list.

Comment: please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68979326/flutter-how-to-groupby-inside-a-mapentry/68979470#68979470

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you implement a sorting algorithm with O(n^2) time complexity by your own?
You can use

```
List<OnlineDeliveryOrder> getSortedOrdersList(List<OnlineDeliveryOrder> orderList){
    var format = DateFormat('hh:mm a');
    return List.of(orderList)..sort((a,b){
        if(a.deliveryTime == null) return 1;
        if(b.deliveryTime == null) return -1;
        if(a.deliveryTime == 'ASAP') return 1;
        if(b.deliveryTime == 'ASAP') return -1;
        return format.parse(a.deliveryTime).compareTo(format.parse(b.deliveryTime));
    });
}
```

This way, first all objects come with valid date, then with `'ASAP'` and then with `null` as `deliveryTime`.

Or if you want it even more efficient without any package:

```
class SortObject extends Comparable<SortObject>{
   static final DateFormat format = DateFormat('hh:mm a');
   final OnlineDeliveryOrder order;
   final DateTime? deliveryTime;

   SortObject(this.order):this.deliveryTime=order.deliveryTime==null||order.deliveryTime=='ASAP'?null:format.parse(order.deliveryTime);

   int compareTo(SortObject other){
            if(order.deliveryTime == null) return 1;
            if(other.order.deliveryTime == null) return -1;
            if(order.deliveryTime == 'ASAP') return 1;
            if(other.order.deliveryTime == 'ASAP') return -1;
            return deliveryTime!.compareTo(other.deliveryTime!);
   }
}

List<OnlineDeliveryOrder> getSortedOrdersList(List<OnlineDeliveryOrder> orderList){
    return (orderList.map((a)=>SortObject(a)).toList()..sort((a,b){
        return a.compareTo(b);
    })).map((a)=>a.order).toList();
}
```

Or did I get the question wrong?
If there are errors in the code, I apologize. I just wrote it down.

I would recommend you to add in the `OnlineDeliveryOrder` class another attribute that stores the `DateTime` in addition to `deliveryTime` which does that as a `String`. Or you can store the time only as `DateTime` and not as `String` at all. If you receive the data as JSON, this is very easy to do. (This way you wouldn't need an extra class or a `GroupedList`).

Comment: @Nagual This way, `null` values would no longer come after `'ASAP'` values. But it would satisfy the requirements.